# Show the percent change week on week Data Studio

Tags: google, google-data-studio

In Data studio I'm trying to get the percentage change week on week of a metric so that weekly reporting on changes is automated - right now I have to calculate the differences manually every week.

Visually this is the idea, but any type of chart / visualisation would be fine. Is this possible in Data studio?

[image]